# SQL Column value as table name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select from multiple tables based on a value from first table.
How can I use the value of `a.property_type` as a table name?

```
SELECT * from properties a
//LEFT JOIN caracteristics_apartments
LEFT JOIN caracteristics_+a.property_type b
ON a.property_id = b.property_id
WHERE a.property_id = 1
```

So if I have a record in properties:

```
id_property: 1
property_name: Apartment 3 rooms
property_type: apartment
```

then I use the value from property_type to select from another table named apartment_characteristics (composed by property_type + "_characteristics") to get the property characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is usually a sign that the database design isn't properly normalised and could do with some refactoring to combine the core fields you're trying to join against into a single coherent table; I'd look at that as a first port of call.

Otherwise - it's not possible for the same query to join on different tables for different rows, they all have to join to the same place. You can build a dynamic query at runtime to select from each individual table, but again that's not really a great idea in practice; it can be quite fragile and slow.

If you *really* have to do something along these lines, what you'll need to join is LEFT JOIN against all possible tables for alias b (side note - meaningful namaes make things so much easier to debug than a, b, c etc.) then use COALESCE to combine their values to combine their columns into a single shape. But I wouldn't do that; the code is likely to be huge and unwieldy, and it won't be especially clear to the application which bit of data has come from where.

Comment: I will go for your first idea. I did not designed the database this way, but I was intended to. Now I will cancel the idea. The problem is that I have a main table with properties, and for each type of property a set of characteristics. For example apartments have 10, lands have 3, house have 6. In total 19 columns. All ok but only when I insert a land 16 will be null or 0 and I don't like it. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score -2):

(**Edited**)This is for normal joins, SO, Please don't consider this answer:

Select a.property_type as property_type,
 b.property_value as property_value
from Property_table_a a, Property_table_b b
where a.property_id = b.property_id

For left outer join or right outer join, you use:

where a.property_id = b.property_id(+)

This is mainly preferred in Oracle database.